# Particle Orthographic Clipping Issues

Tags: particles, camera, orthographic, clipping

I just got done following a tutorial for creating an asteroid field by setting them to a volumed hair particle system, but I'm having some strange issues with them clipping in orthographic view camera.

First off, in the viewport, the particles appear as they should with the animated moving emitter working fine, but when I enter the camera view there is some weird clipping as the asteroids move (see between frame 287 - 344). I've tried messing with the clip start and end point in the camera settings but I cant seem to get it to work.

Please see the [attached file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kPG0dl6ksqedbqCjrQLnv0Vp4GKD3Tba/view?usp=drive_link), I've been pulling my hair out over this all morning

Answer (score 0):

Ignore this, I had the camera placed within the asteroid field so objects were passing through the physical camera object. Fixed!